# .jar plugin for Eclipse not being loaded

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to install FatJar plugin in Eclipse, but it is not showing up. I am doing everything as explained in the [documentation](http://fjep.sourceforge.net/#inst), extracted the .jar file in `plugins` directory, then started command prompt inside Eclipse folder with "eclipse -clean", and it doesn't show up...

Anyone know how can I check if the plugin is being noticed at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This plugin is very old and is using the old style plugin format which is not supported by default by current versions of Eclipse.

As mentioned in the documentation most (probably all) of the features provided by this plugin are now part of Eclipse as standard (see 'File > Export > Java > Runnable JAR file')

Comment: I think this won't work for me, as I need to export a project as a .jar file for Android project (meaning runnable jar file probably is not the option I need)

Comment: I don't know much about Android development but I thought the ADT plugins provided everything needed for Android. However Google are dropping support for Eclipse so moving to Android Studio is now recommended.

Comment: yes, but Android Studio does not have the option to create a .jar

Comment: I suggest you ask a new question tagged with [tag:android] asking how to do what you want.